# input event - losing focus while dragging input element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a score module using a range input. I'm using the `input` event to achieve this. The range input works fine, but when I add event, it loses focus shortly after dragging begins.

This is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot]

```js
document.querySelector("#score").addEventListener("input", e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="10" draggable="true" class="score theme" id="score" step="0.1">
```

Comment: may you add the html fragment? Thanks

Comment: Is "score" the class name, ID, or element type?

Comment: @caseyjhol sorry its id name I forgot to add here

Comment: @gaetanoM I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you added `draggable="true"` to the element. So the behaviour is ambiguous, should the browser allow you to move the trackball or should the browser drag the element around the page?

The two behaviours are conflicting, so in the first moment it works properly as an input range and you're able to move it around, but then it allows you to drag the element.

What's your expected behaviour?

```js
document.querySelector("#score").addEventListener("input", e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
 });
```

```html
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="10" class="score theme" id="score" step="0.1">
```

Answer (score 2):

`draggable="true"` doesn’t do what you think it does. An `<input type="range">` has a draggable component to it by default. The [`draggable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable) makes it so that you can drag the *entire* element.

Removing this attribute gives the expected behaviour:

```js
document.getElementById('score').addEventListener('input', e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="10" id="score" step="0.1">
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with the `draggable="true"` attribute and not the JavaScript code. The `draggable` attribute allows us to make the element draggable around the DOM, i.e. from one position to another in the viewport.

Therefore, when one tries to drag the range handle, the whole slider gets dragged along, instead of just the handle, which is what you described as "losing focus".

So, the solution is to simply remove the `draggable=true` attribute. I made a pen on CodePen to demonstrate this. https://codepen.io/aryan_02/pen/WPNBYm

Notice what the `draggable` attribute does. I hope this helps you.